# how to change en-US dates to en-GB for asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, datetime-format

on a developer machine (cassini)

```
new DateTime(2012,3,14).ToString("d")
```

results in

```
14/03/2012
```

which is correct but when deployed to a full IIS server the result is

```
03/14/2012
```

The server is set in control panel/Region language to all English/UK/GB, running date in command prompt returns the dd/MM/YYYY format.

The site is set for both `uiCulture="en-GB"` and `culture="en-GB"` and these show in the web.config globalization tag.

I can work around this issue by adding a forced culture

```
new DateTime(2012,3,14).ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

but I would really like to know what is setting the format incorrectly.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name
```

both return `en-US`

---

- **en-US**: `M/d/yyyy`  (e.g. 3/14/2012)
- **en-GB**: `dd/MM/yyyy`  (e.g. 14/03/2012)

Actual value in web.config

```
 <globalization requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

Comment: Post the snippet from the `globalization` section of your `web.config`. The locale used to convert dates and numbers comes from `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`; what culture does that return?

Comment: Off subject: have you considered using IIS Express rather than Casini to better get the same results as in production on IIS?

Answer (score 31):

I managed to get it working by putting this into the web.config

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"/>
```

Comment: I think its n the question itself *The site is set for both uiCulture="en-GB" and culture="en-GB" and these show in the web.config globalization tag.*

Comment: That's good, if you want to take it further, you can also add it to the Machine.config file in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[framework version]\Config\Machine.config (or similar path).  Then the change will apply to all .NET applications, but not affect the general globalisation settings on the server.

Comment: my understanding was that the web.config trumps the machine.config

Answer (score 5):

In your `web.config` add

```
<globalization culture='auto' uiCulture='auto' />
```

and then, assuming the browser is correctly configured to pass the preferred locale, the worker thread processing the request will have its `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` set correctly.

Any locale dependent operations (including such things as `DateTime` format `d`) will use the client's preference.

Globalization element of web.config on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkak5b9(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: before I started looking into the issue the globalization tag only had the UTF-8 setting and I tried multiple browsers/machines to ensure that the browser was not the culprit.

Comment: @rob What is the HTTP request's `Accept-Language` header? ([Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is an incredibly useful tool in these cases).

Comment: IE9 sends `Accept-Language: en-GB`
and Chrome sends `Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6`

Comment: @rob I've just re-tested: using IIS7.5 & .NET 4.5 (Beta) on Win2k8R2. System locale is en-GB so without `<globalization>` get en-GB/en-US (culture/UI-culture). With `<globalization ...auto...auto/>` the browser is followed: request has fr-FR then thread is using fr-FR for both culture and UI-culture (and an en-GB request now has both culture *and* UI-culture of en-GB). What version of .NET and IIS are you using?

Comment: w2k8[Standard] SP2(64 bit) IIS7 .NET 4.0.30319

Comment: @rob OK... working for me as descrivbed previously on another VM: Win2k8 Std (x86) with .NET 4.0.30319. I suspect some component is interfering... but that will be hard to find.